# Javascript / What I'm typing is what I'm seeing

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field and a destination < span >. So, I want the typed data to appear simultaneously within my destination < span >...< /span>.

```
button.onclick = function() {
var newEvent = document.getElementById('event');//it's my input field
var spanNewEvent = document.querySelector('dataEvent');//it's my destination place <span>...</span>
newEvent.innerHTML = spanNewEvent.innerHTML;//does not work
```

The HTML code:

```
<span class = "spanEvent" data-event= "spanEvent"></span>
<form>...<input data-type-event="text" placeholder="Event" id="event">...</form>
```

Please, help! Have been struggling against it for too long tonight. Thank you in advance!

Comment: this code is assigned to the onclick for a button, so it is only going to execute when you click a button... what button in your HTML is triggering it?

Comment: You're trying to set your input field's inner html to your span's inner html.

Comment: flip newEvent.innerHTML and spanNewEvent.innerHTML and change the newEvent to newEvent.value

Comment: querySelector `dataEvent` will select the first element of type `dataEvent`. I doubt whether you have a `dataEvent` tag in your page. I think this is meant to be `'.spanEvent'` or `'span[data-event="spanEvent"]'`.

Comment: @AndrewCounts Yeah I know. It's a submit button. But it does nix when I click it.

        var button = document.getElementById('done');
        button.onclick = function() {
          var newEvent = document.getElementById('event');
          var spanNewEvent = document.querySelector('dataEvent');
          newEvent.innerHTML = spanNewEvent.innerHTML;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, you will need to give your span the id "dataEvent" to make it easier:

```
var newEvent = document.getElementById('event');//it's my input field
var spanNewEvent = document.querySelector('dataEvent');

    newEvent.addEventListener('keyup', showthereto);

function showthereto() {
    document.getElementById('dataEvent').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Comment: console.log shows:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of nullindex
showthereto

Comment: Now I did. But it does nothing. Though, no messages in console.

Answer (score 1):

The typed data will not appear simultaneously since you are putting your code in an `onclick` function, so you'll have to click the button to get the text to appear in the `span`.

You're also not selecting the input correctly, so to fix that you'll need to use `var spanNewEvent = document.querySelector('#event');`

Additionally, you'll need to use `value` to get the data from the input field like this: `newEvent.innerHTML = spanNewEvent.value;`

Comment: though there's my typed text 
console.log shows:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Answer edited - that error indicates that your `querySelector` is not properly targeting the input element.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("event").addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector(".spanEvent").textContent = this.value;
});
```